# Help with notation in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Here is a question from a final I am doing
[image]

I need help with understanding what exactly it means with $p(0)$ or $p(1)=0$ mean. I know that $p(x)=c_0+c_1x^1+c_2x^2+...+c_nx^n$ so does that mean $p(0)=0+0x^1+0x^2+0x^3+...+0x^n=0$? and $p(1)=1+x^1+x^2+x^3+...+x^n$?

Comment: You should be replacing $x$ with 0 or 1, not the coefficients of the polynomials.

Comment: No, as you've probably seen before, polynomials determine a function by actually plugging in a value for $x$. Thus $p(0) = c_0 + c_10 + c_20^2+...+c_n0^n = c_0$

Comment: No, $p(b)$ is the **value** of $p(x)$ when you plug in $b$ for $x$. So for your general $p(x)$, we have $p(0)=c_0$ and $p(1)=c_0+c_1+\cdots +c_n$.

Comment: Be careful: $P(0) = c_n(0)^n + \cdots + c_1(0) + c_0$.

Answer (score 0):

You substitute for the argument ($x$) not the coefficients.

$\because p_n(x) = c_0+ c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + \cdots + c_n x^n$

$\therefore p_n(0) = c_0 + c_1 (0) + c_2 (0)^2 + \cdots + c_n (0)^n = c_0$

$\therefore p_n(1) = c_0 + c_1 (1) + c_2 (1)^2 + \cdots + c_n (1)^n = c_0 + c_1 + c_2 + \cdots + c_n$

So for quadratic polynomials (ie: $p_2(x)=c_0+c_1 x + c_2 x^2$) $$p_2(0)=0 \implies c_0 = 0 \\ p_2(1)=0 \implies c_0+c_1+c_2 = 0$$